Can I use a colon to introduce direct speech, if I continue the sentence after the quote?
Can I use a colon to introduce direct speech, if I continue the sentence after the quote? There are a lot of examples on the Internet where a quote stands between an introductory phrase and a clause that continues the sentence after the direct speech, but in most cases there are commas before and after the quote.
The question is the following: can I use a colon before the quote instead of a comma and do I need to use some specific punctuation after the direct speech in this case?
For example:

There is a saying: "The road to hell is paved with good intentions," and I agree with this phrase.


The problem with the colon is that it seems to apply to all that follows. There is a saying: ("The road to hell is paved with good intentions," and I agree with this phrase.)

There are several questions on how to punctuate similar things: quotation in mid-sentence, one-word quote, quote ending in question mark. A colon is not the usual way of doing this. When you know something is non-standard but want to do it anyway, you should explain why.

Far better is  << There is a saying: "The road to hell is paved with good intentions." And I agree with this expression. >> Yosef makes a telling point. In line with this, colons are never paired. But a pair of dashes is a possible alternative.

I can't see where the coordinated independent clause coming after a quote introduced by a colon is covered elsewhere.

In the example given, you can use the colon if you move your statement before the colon:
There is a saying, and I agree with this phrase: The road to hell is paved with good intentions.
Otherwise, I believe in most cases, the only thing following the colon should be the statement that the colon introduces. This applies to not just quotes, but to any introductory text followed by an elucidation or list of specifics.
For example:
Real estate agents all say one thing is most important: "Location, location, location."
There are four ingredient in basic bread: flour, water, yeast, and shortening.
Chemists recognize two kinds of bonds in molecules: covalent and ionic.
Space: the final frontier. These are the voyages of the starship Enterprise. Its five-year mission: to explore strange new worlds; to seek out new life and new civilizations; to boldly go where no man has gone before!
